# Convert mat file to pandas dataframe problem

Tags: python, pandas, matlab, dictionary, converters

Hello I'm stuck on getting good conversion of a matrix of matlab to pandas dataframe. 
I converted it but I've got one row in which I've list of list. These list of list are normaly my rows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.io.matlab import mio
Data_mat = mio.loadmat('senet50-ferplus-logits.mat')
```

my `Data_mat.keys()` gives me this output:

```
dict_keys(['__header__', '__version__', '__globals__', 'images', 'wavLogits'])
```

I'd like to convert `images` and `wavLogits` to data frame.
By looking to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45007081/8333806) I applied the solution.

```
cardio_df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((Data_mat['images'], Data_mat['wavLogits'])))
```

And the output is
[image: df]

How to get the df in good format?

**[UPDATE]** `Data_mat["images"]` has

```
array([[(array([[array(['A.J._Buckley/test/Y8hIVOBuels_0000001.wav'], dtype='<U41'),
        array(['A.J._Buckley/test/Y8hIVOBuels_0000002.wav'], dtype='<U41'),
        array(['A.J._Buckley/test/Y8hIVOBuels_0000003.wav'], dtype='<U41'),
        ...,
        array(['Zulay_Henao/train/s4R4hvqrhFw_0000007.wav'], dtype='<U41'),
        array(['Zulay_Henao/train/s4R4hvqrhFw_0000008.wav'], dtype='<U41'),
        array(['Zulay_Henao/train/s4R4hvqrhFw_0000009.wav'], dtype='<U41')]],
      dtype=object), array([[     1,      2,      3, ..., 153484, 153485, 153486]], dtype=int32), array([[   1,    1,    1, ..., 1251, 1251, 1251]], dtype=uint16), array([[array(['Y8hIVOBuels'], dtype='<U11'),
        array(['Y8hIVOBuels'], dtype='<U11'),
        array(['Y8hIVOBuels'], dtype='<U11'), ...,
        array(['s4R4hvqrhFw'], dtype='<U11'),
        array(['s4R4hvqrhFw'], dtype='<U11'),
        array(['s4R4hvqrhFw'], dtype='<U11')]], dtype=object), array([[1, 2, 3, ..., 7, 8, 9]], dtype=uint8), array([[array(['A.J._Buckley/1.6/Y8hIVOBuels/1/01.jpg'], dtype='<U37')],
       [array(['A.J._Buckley/1.6/Y8hIVOBuels/1/02.jpg'], dtype='<U37')],
       [array(['A.J._Buckley/1.6/Y8hIVOBuels/1/03.jpg'], dtype='<U37')],
       ...,
       [array(['Zulay_Henao/1.6/s4R4hvqrhFw/9/16.jpg'], dtype='<U36')],
       [array(['Zulay_Henao/1.6/s4R4hvqrhFw/9/17.jpg'], dtype='<U36')],
       [array(['Zulay_Henao/1.6/s4R4hvqrhFw/9/18.jpg'], dtype='<U36')]],
      dtype=object), array([[1.00000e+00],
       [1.00000e+00],
       [1.00000e+00],
       ...,
       [1.53486e+05],
       [1.53486e+05],
       [1.53486e+05]], dtype=float32), array([[3, 3, 3, ..., 1, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8))]],
      dtype=[('name', 'O'), ('id', 'O'), ('sp', 'O'), ('video', 'O'), ('track', 'O'), ('denseFrames', 'O'), ('denseFramesWavIds', 'O'), ('set', 'O')])
```

Comment: what is the dimensions of `Data_mat["images"]`. is it a numpy matrix? or is it a list of matrices?

Comment: It's an `numpy.ndarray` the shape gives me `(1,1)`.

Comment: I updated the post for the output of `Data_mat["images"]`

Comment: yeah, I think thats the problem.  Pandas is expecting a numpy array of shape (n,m) where n is number of rows, and m is number of columns. You essentially want to flatten your data into one array. This might be good start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33711985/flattening-a-list-of-numpy-arrays

Comment: thanks let me look it.

Comment: Do you have access to Matlab? If so, another option would be to load the .mat file in Matlab, and saving it in a different format, say csv or parquet with the `writetable` and `parquetwrite` functions

Comment: I do not have matlab!

Comment: Still stuck any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is what I'd do to convert a mat file into a pandas dataframe automagically.

```py
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('file.mat')
mat = {k:v for k, v in mat.items() if k[0] != '_'}
df = pd.DataFrame({k: np.array(v).flatten() for k, v in mat.items()})
```